# A question in mean-value formula?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $ u \in C^2 (\Omega) $ be a harmonic function on $ \Omega $, $ B[x,r] \subseteq \Omega $ a closed ball. Set 
\begin{equation*}
\psi(r) := \int_{\partial B(0,1) } u(x+rz)dS(z),
\end{equation*}
How can we determine that $ \psi'(r) $ can be obtained by differentiation under integral?

Comment: It follows cleanly by choosing an explicit parameterisation and the usual theorem for differentiating under a 1D integral. What have you tried?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I search the rule of differentiation under integral in standard book of analysis and find the version is given in terms of rectangle case. Here the variable $ z \in \partial B(0,1) $, thus, i feel some confuse. Could you give a clean explanation?

Comment: Use an explicit parameterisation. This is a map from some rectangles $[a_1,b_1] \times \dots \times [a_{n-1} , b_{n-1} ]$ into $\partial B(0,1)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the ambient $\mathbb R^n \supset \Omega $. Then use that rule. Then undo the parameterisation. For instance in dimension 2 $\partial B(0,1)$ is a circle and there is a well known map $[0,2\pi) \to \partial B(0,1)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ok, i get it. Thank you.